# Raid controller not claimed after CentOS 8 upgrade

Tags: linux, centos, raid

I had a CentOS 7 installed on a machine, and MegaRaid storcli64 was able to detect the controller and disks. At that time, lshw shown:

```
*-raid
    description: RAID bus controller
    product: MegaRAID SAS 2108 [Liberator]
    vendor: Broadcom / LSI
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
    version: 05
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: raid pm pciexpress vpd msi msix bus_master cap_list rom
    configuration: driver=megaraid_sas latency=0
    resources: irq:24 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fb360000-fb363fff memory:fb300000-fb33ffff memory:fb340000-fb35ffff
```

After upgrading to CentOS 8, storcli64 no longer is able to detect the controller. Now, lshw shows:

```
*-raid UNCLAIMED
    description: RAID bus controller
    product: MegaRAID SAS 2108 [Liberator]
    vendor: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
    version: 05
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: raid pm pciexpress vpd msi msix bus_master cap_list
    configuration: latency=0
    resources: ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fb360000-fb363fff memory:fb300000-fb33ffff memory:fb340000-fb35ffff
```

Note the UNCLAIMED, and note the lack of a driver. Nevertheless:

```
$ lsmod|grep sas
megaraid_sas          155648  0
```

Any hint on what might be going on?

**NOTE:** noted this in dmesg: '[    3.208471] Warning: megaraid_sas 0000:01:00.0 [1000:0079] - Support for this device has been removed in this major release. Please check the removed functionality section of the release notes.' It seems I need to go back to CentOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like support for this specific hardware was removed. I found this post, where the community is requesting for the driver to be readded, as it is still widely used.

While no official answer is presented, some user RPMs for the kernel with support for this hardware is available at that same URL. After installing them raid is back.